# Do i need to install rundeck software before using the rundeck-cli

Tags: rundeck

This is my first time using Rundeck. Do I need to install the Rundeck software (GUI version) on linux before I use the CLI version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically no, you can install Rundeck CLI without Rundeck, but Rundeck CLI must interact with a Rundeck instance, for example: you can install Rundeck CLI on your laptop pointing to a remote Rundeck server (Docker, Windows, Linux, etc) and use Rundeck CLI from your machine.

Rundeck CLI is a Rundeck API abstraction client.

You can configure RD CLI against your Rundeck instance following [this](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/configuration/).

Comment: How do I point to a remote Rundeck server? I am using Rundeck in a container

Comment: Configure RD CLI using the hostname with the credentials (user/password or token), take a look at this: https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/configuration/

Comment: Awesome! please accept the answer to help other users with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers